# The root assembly conflicts with another assembly

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

Previously I was using **Xamarin Studio** to build the App and it was working perfectly fine. Now I copied the same solution and try to build on **Visual Studio** through **Xamarin Mac Agent**. whenever I try to run the App, I am getting following error:

> **The root assembly**
>
> /Users/eagle/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/App1.iOS/3592b16d5f6494c29443153f9249eb47/bin/iPhone/Debug/App1.exe
>
> **conflicts with another assembly**
>
> (/Users/eagle/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/App1.iOS/3592b16d5f6494c29443153f9249eb47/bin/iPhone/Debug/App1.exe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Upgrade the VS to current stable channel version, refer to [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/92773/the-root-assembly-conflicts-with-another-assembly)
- Try to rename **Application Name** in your project in visual studio,since both two assembly would be referred to same place.